# Fetch pagination links

Tags: php, regex, http, curl, preg-match-all

I am new with php. What i am trying to do is to fetch the links of the pagination. The page has pagination on it and the links ofcourse changes as we choose the page. How can I fetch the url's of the paginations by staying on the main page which is `http://ahadith.co.uk/sahihmuslim.php`.

```
<?php 
        $ch = curl_init(); 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://ahadith.co.uk/sahihmuslim.php"); 
//fetches data from the site mentioned above
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
        $output = curl_exec($ch); 

        $pattern = "/href=[']([^'][a-zA-Z]+.[a-zA-Z]+.[cid]+=[0-9]+)[']?/";
//this regex brings the links from the above url
        preg_match_all($pattern, $output, $matches, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
        foreach ($matches[1] as $data) {
        $homepage = file_get_contents('http://ahadith.co.uk/'.$data);
//all the links data which was caught above using regex has been stored in $homepage
        $pattern_chapter= "/(?<=\<h2\>)(\s*.*\s*)(?=\<\/h2\>)/";
//Here I have fetched the chapters from the data stored in $homepage
        preg_match_all($pattern_chapter, $homepage, $matches_chapter, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
        foreach ($matches_chapter[1] as $chapters) {
        print_r($chapters);
        }
?>
```

Now i have to get the links of the pagination from the data which is stored in `$homepage`. Like in this case pagination has 44 pages and i want to get links of all the 44 pages. This is the regex which matches the links which are in the pagination `http:\/\/([a-zA-Z]+.[a-zA-Z]+.[a-zA-Z]+.[a-zA-Z]+.[a-zA-Z]+.[cid]+=[0-9]&[a-zA-Z]+=[0-9]&[a-zA-Z]+=[0-9]+)`
I have searched many places for this but couldn't find anything related to this. Please can anyone help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

Use "HtmlPageDom". it's a third party library for easy manipulation of HTML documents using DOM. you can extract any kind of data what you want from any page.

https://github.com/wasinger/htmlpagedom/blob/master/README.md

Comment: For this i will have to start all over again, Is there any other way which i can use here to get the links from pagination?